# Android socket io event and Channel

Tags: java, android, sockets, socket.io

How to add event and channel?

```
private void initSocketConnection() {
    try {
        mSocket = IO.socket("URL");
        connectSocket();
    } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}

private void connectSocket() {
    try {
        mSocket.connect();
        mSocket.on(Socket.EVENT_CONNECT, onConnect);
        mSocket.on(Socket.EVENT_CONNECT_ERROR, onError);
        mSocket.on(Socket.EVENT_DISCONNECT, onDisconnect);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private Emitter.Listener onDisconnect = new Emitter.Listener() {
    @Override
    public void call(Object... args) {
        Log.e("SOCKET_TEST", "DISCONNECTION SUCCESSFULL");
    }
};


/**
 * Receiver class for socket connected event
 */
private Emitter.Listener onConnect = new Emitter.Listener() {
    @Override
    public void call(Object... args) {
        Log.e("SOCKET_TEST", "CONNECTION SUCCESSFULL");
    }
};

/**
 * Receiver for socket failed events
 */
private Emitter.Listener onError = new Emitter.Listener() {
    @Override
    public void call(Object... args) {
        Log.e("SOCKET_TEST", "CONNECTION FAIL " + args.toString());
    }
};
```

I send a request, returns `32:44/socket.io,"Invalid namespace"`
need to send event and channel

I use the library https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client-java I do everything according to the documentation but nothing works.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating a socket with just:

```
val socket = IO.socket("https://something.com/socket.io")
```

try the next code:

```
val opts = IO.Options()
opts.path = "/socket.io"

val socket = IO.socket("https://something.com", opts)
```

I had the same issue getting `4/socket.io, "Invalid namespace"` trying to connect to the socket, and the code above fixed it.